# How can I create an IDOMFont instance for a font file?

Tags: c++, pdf, pdf-generation, mako-sdk

I'm using the Mako SDK and I need to create an `IDOMFont` instance for use in other APIs, but I can't see how to do this.

The font is an OpenType font and located locally on disk.

I've seen `IInputStream`, but I don't know how I can use this to create an `IDOMFont` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font instance can be created using the following API:

```
static EDL_API IDOMFontOpenTypePtr create(IEDLClassFactory *pFactory, const IInputStreamPtr &stream);
```

To use the API, you can use code similar to the following:

```
IInputStreamPtr fontStream = IInputStream::createFromFile(jawsMako, "myfont.otf");
IDOMFontPtr font = IDOMFontOpenType::create(jawsMako, fontStream);
```

For more information, see:

https://api.globalgraphics.com/mako/a00712.html

https://api.globalgraphics.com/mako/a01080.html